# スプレッドシートに対してリクエスト上限以上の操作を行いたい

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

https://tanuhack.com/operate-spreadsheet/#Python

このサイトを参考に、Pythonプログラムからスプレッドシート上にデータを書き込む操作を行っています。

上記ページ内情報によると「1回のプログラムで設定できる最大値は1,000件まで」なのですが、その場合スプレッドシートに対して1つのプログラムだと1000個のセルまでしか操作できないことになってしまいます。
それ以上の個数のセルに対して操作を行いたい場合、1000個の処理毎に**別のプログラムに分けて**アクセスし操作を行うしかないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

## 回答

上限を超えた操作をすべきではありませんが、
1000個の処理毎に別のプログラムに分ける必要はないと思います。
ただし、他に制限があり、そちらは考慮すべきです。

## 参考にされたページの情報源(と思われるページ）

「https://tanuhack.com/operate-spreadsheet/#Python」の情報源は、確証はありませんが、「[API リクエストの制限と割り当て](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas?hl=ja)」ではないでしょうか。

以下は引用(抜粋)です。

**一般的な割り当て制限**

以下の割り当ては Management API、Core Reporting API v3、MCF Reporting API、Metadata API、User Deletion API、Real Time Reporting API に適用されます。

- プロジェクトごとの 1 日あたりのリクエスト数は 50,000 件（引き上げ可能）。
- IP アドレスごとの 1 秒あたりのクエリ数（QPS）は 10 件。

  - API Console には、ユーザーごとの 100 秒あたりのリクエスト数という類似の割り当て制限があります。デフォルトでは、ユーザーごとに 100 秒あたり 100 件のリクエストに設定されています。設定できる最大値は 1,000 件です。ただし、API に対するリクエスト数は、ユーザーごとに 1 秒あたり 10 件までに制限されています。
  - アプリケーションが、すべての API リクエストを 1 つの IP アドレスから行う（つまり、ユーザーに代わってリクエストを行う）場合は、ユーザーごとに QPS が上限まで割り当てられるように各リクエストで userIP パラメータまたは quotaUser パラメータを使用してください。詳しくは、標準クエリ パラメータの概要をご覧ください。

---

## 考慮すべき制限

質問された方が参考にされたページでも言及されているようですが、次の制限値を考慮する必要があると思います。

「[API リクエストの制限と割り当て](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas?hl=ja)」に記載されている制限値

- 100 秒あたりのリクエスト数100件
- API に対するリクエスト数は、ユーザーごとに1秒あたり10件までに制限されています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 自分でも試してみた所、1,000件は大幅に上回るリクエストを送ることができたので、どうやら1,000件という制限はないし従って分割する必要もないのですね。 （結局ブログ記事にある「1回のプログラムで設定できる最大値は1,000件まで」は正しくないということなのでしょうか…）

Comment: 「API リクエストの制限と割り当て」に書いてある制限「100 秒あたり 100 件のリクエストに設定されています。設定できる最大値は 1,000 件です。」をinsさんが参考にされたブログでは「1回のプログラムで設定できる最大値は1,000件まで」と表現したのではないかと推測しました。プログラムを分けたかはgoogleにとって知りようのないことで、それが制限になるのはおかしいとも考えました。insさんの質問で私もスプレッドシートを使ってみようかなと思いました。